# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core cannot compare 'object' type

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to run a dynamic query with a model as below:

```
public class Index
{
    public long Position { get; set; }

    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

And with a sample of data like this:

```
var indexes = new Dictionary<long, Index>();
indexes.Add(1, new Index { Position = 1000, Values = new object[3] { "Welly", "Chandra", 26 } });
indexes.Add(2, new Index { Position = 1001, Values = new object[3] { "Darma", "Angelo", 25 } });
indexes.Add(3, new Index { Position = 1002, Values = new object[3] { "Abby", "Yeremia", 28 } });
indexes.Add(4, new Index { Position = 1003, Values = new object[3] { "Yonathan", "Gunawan", 22 } });
indexes.Add(5, new Index { Position = 1004, Values = new object[3] { "Aldy", "Santoso", 24 } });
var queryable = indexes.Values.AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.Where("Values[1] = \"Yeremia\" || Values[2] = 24").ToList();
```

But it always throw an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Object' and 'System.Int32'.
```

Is it not possible to use `object` data type here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you use `.Equals()`, which will first check to see if the types are identical and, if they are not, will perform a cast to the run-time type.

```
var result = queryable.Where(
    "Values[1].Equals(\"Yeremia\") || Values[2].Equals(24)").ToList();
```

As noted in the comments, there are challenges when comparing objects.  In the case of `==`, you cannot compare `Int32` to object without a cast.  Likewise, when using `.Equals()`, you cannot have the left-hand value be null otherwise you will throw a NullReferenceException.

If possible, a vastly better approach would be something like a ValueTuple that is strongly typed and referenced by name rather than index.  Not only is this safe from NullReferenceExceptions, but it avoids boxing and casting operations as well.

```
public class Index
{
    public long Position { get; set; }
    public (string, string, int) Values { get; set; }
}
```

```
var indexes = new Dictionary<long, Index>();
    indexes.Add(1, new Index { Position = 1000, Values = ("Welly", "Chandra", 26) });
    indexes.Add(2, new Index { Position = 1001, Values = ("Darma", "Angelo", 25) });
    indexes.Add(3, new Index { Position = 1002, Values = ("Abby", "Yeremia", 28) });
    indexes.Add(4, new Index { Position = 1003, Values = ("Yonathan", "Gunawan", 22) });
    indexes.Add(5, new Index { Position = 1004, Values = ("Aldy", "Santoso", 24) });
    
var queryable = indexes.Values.AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.Where(
    "Values.Item2 == \"Yeremia\" || Values.Item3 == 24").ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. So, is it better for all comparisons to use `.Equals()` instead of `=` operator?

Comment: `So, is it better for all comparisons to use .Equals() instead of = operator?` Not if the left side can be `null`.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan as is always the case with these sort of things, the answer is "it depends".  mjwills highlight a perfect example of when it wouldn't be advisable...in cases where you might cause a NullReferenceException for instance.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I can guarantee for the `object[]` Values, they will always have a `not null` value.

Comment: It might be possible with `ValueTuple`, but since my `Values`'s length is not definite and has a dynamic type, I think I need to use `Array` instead.